# count letter in words using Python

Tags: python

I am working with Python to write a function
Here is an example: `lettercount([‘hello’,’it’,’is’,’me’],’i’)` should return `[’it-1’,’is-1’]`.

Here is my code:

```
def lettercount(list, letter):
    result = []           #create an empty list
    for word in list:            #traverse through all the words in the provided list
        if word not in result:        #from this line I don't know what I'm really doing though
            if letter in word:                
                wrd = "{}-".format(word).append(word.count(letter))     
 #tried to achieve the same format as provided but failed
                result.append(wrd)               #this is wrong because str doesn't have the attribute "append"
    return result
```

Can someone give me a hint on this problem? Thanks so much!

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `wrd = "{}-{}".format(word, word.count(letter))`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you construct `wrd`. Change this line -

```
wrd = "{}-".format(word).append(word.count(letter))
```

To -

```
wrd = f"{word}-{word.count(letter)}"
```

P.s please. avoid using `list` as a name of a variable and use, for example, `lst` instead since `list` is a protected word in Python.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def lettercount(lst, letter):
    out = []
    for word in lst:
        cnt = sum(1 for l in word if l == letter)
        if cnt:
            out.append(f'{word}-{cnt}')
    return out
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def lettercount(lst, letter):
    result = []
    for word in lst:
        if letter in word:
            result.append(word + '-' + str(word.count(letter)))
```

And I don't recommend naming variables "list" because it's an existing keyword in Python.